# Is it possible to perform a FFT on my dataset using FFTW in C++?

Tags: c++, fft, physics, fftw

I'm writing a program to compute the Fourier transform of a set of complex matrices at N discrete points along a line in 3D k-space, from k=(0, 0, 1/2) to k=(1/2, 1/3, 1/2).

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9kCU.png) is the formula I am trying to compute.

Here is my current working implementation, using the Eigen C++ package for matrix operations:
(k_coordinates is a 3xN vector, and R_coordinates is a 3x1155 vector)

```cpp
// Perform Fourier transform on H(R) to get H(k)
    Matrix18 H_k_data[k_coordinates.size()]; // 2*N array of 18x18 matrices
    for (int k_index=0; k_index<k_coordinates.size(); k_index++) { // Loop over k points
        for (int R=0; R<1155; R++) { // Loop over R points
            // Calculate dot product k.R
            double k_dot_R = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
                k_dot_R += (k_coordinates[k_index][i] * R_coordinates_data[R][i] * 2 * M_PI);
            }
            std::complex<double> phase_factor = std::polar(1.0, -k_dot_R); // Compute phase factor as e^(-ik.r)

            // Add final value to H(k) at each index
            H_k_data[k_index] += (H_R_data[R] * phase_factor);
        }
    }
```

This works but is very slow so I'm trying to implement the FFT algorithm using the FFTW C++ library, however I can't figure out how to set up my data correctly to use it. I believe I would need to use the fftw_plan_dft_3d() function (3D Discrete Fourier Transform) but can't see how I would actually input my data into the function.

Essentially what I need is for every point k=(kx, ky, kz) in k_coordinates, to calculate the sum over all R coordinates of (H(R) * e^(-2pi * (kxRx + kyRy + kzRz)).

Here is the full code for context:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<complex>
#include<Eigen/Dense>
#include<math.h>
#include<chrono>
#include<fftw3.h>

using namespace Eigen;
typedef Matrix<std::complex<double>, 18, 18> Matrix18;

template<typename T>
std::vector<double> linspace(T start_in, T end_in, int num_in)
{
    std::vector<double> linspaced;

    double start = static_cast<double>(start_in);
    double end = static_cast<double>(end_in);
    double num = static_cast<double>(num_in);

    if (num == 0) {
        return linspaced;
    }
    if (num == 1) {
        linspaced.push_back(start);
        return linspaced;
    }

    double delta = (end - start) / (num - 1);

    for(int i=0; i < num-1; ++i) {
        linspaced.push_back(start + delta * i);
    }
    linspaced.push_back(end);
    return linspaced;
}

std::vector<Matrix18> convert_to_eigen(std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::complex<double>>>> data)
{
    std::vector<Matrix18> data_eigen;
    for (int k=0; k<data.size(); k++){
        Matrix18 H;
        for (int i=0; i<18; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<18; j++) {
                H(i,j) = data[k][i][j];
            }
        }
        data_eigen.push_back(H);
    }
    return data_eigen;
}

void print_message(std::string message, std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point starting_time)
{
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end_convert = std::chrono::steady_clock::now(); 
    std::cout << message << "(" << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(end_convert - starting_time).count() << "s)" << std::endl;
}

std::vector<std::vector<double>> get_k_coordinates()
{
    // Create vector of k coordinates 
    int num_slices = 1000;
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> k_coordinates; // Coordinates of all points along line
    std::vector<double> kx = linspace(0.0, 0.5, num_slices);
    std::vector<double> ky = linspace(0.0, 1.0/3.0, num_slices);
    std::vector<double> kz = linspace(0.5, 0.5, num_slices);

    for (int i=0; i<num_slices; i++) { // Points along L-A
        std::vector<double> slice_coords; // 3x1 vector containing the coordinates of one point along L-A
        slice_coords.push_back(kx[i]);
        slice_coords.push_back(ky[i]);
        slice_coords.push_back(kz[i]);
        k_coordinates.push_back(slice_coords);
    }
    return k_coordinates;
}


int main()
{
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point starting_time = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    print_message("Reading in data...", starting_time);

    std::string filename = "BiTeI_hr_topological.dat";
    std::ifstream data_stream;
    data_stream.open(filename);
    std::string line;
    
    // Read in the R weights data
    std::vector<int> R_weights_data; // 1D Vector to store weights of lattice vectors (1155)
    int lines_to_skip = 3;
    int count = 0;
    while ((count < 77) && std::getline(data_stream, line)) {
        if (lines_to_skip > 0) { // Skip first 3 lines
            lines_to_skip--;
        } else {
            std::istringstream iss(line);
            int num;
            while (iss >> num) {
                R_weights_data.push_back(num);
            }
            count++;
        }
    }

    // Read in hamiltonians and corresponding R coordinate data
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> R_coordinates_data; // 2D Vector to store R coefficients l,m,n (3x1155)
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::complex<double>>>> H_R_data; // 3D vector to store hamiltonians H(R)
    std::vector<std::vector<std::complex<double>>> hamiltonian; // 2D vector to store complex hopping parameters
    std::vector<std::complex<double>> hamiltonian_line; // 1D vector to store single line in hamiltonian
    int line_count = 0;
    while (std::getline(data_stream, line)) {
        std::istringstream iss(line);
        int num;
        
        std::vector<int> R_coordinates_line;
        if (line_count % 324 == 0) {
            
            for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
                iss >> num;
                R_coordinates_line.push_back(num);
            }
            R_coordinates_data.push_back(R_coordinates_line);
        } else {
            for (int i=0; i<3; i++) { // Still skip coefficient characters even when not needed
                iss >> num;
            }
        }
        for (int i=0; i<2; i++){ // Skip index characters
            iss >> num;
        }

        // Read in hamiltonian matrix values
        double real, imag;
        iss >> real;
        iss >> imag;
        std::complex<double> matrix_value(real, imag);
        if (hamiltonian_line.size() == 18) {
            hamiltonian.push_back(hamiltonian_line);
            hamiltonian_line.clear();
        }
        hamiltonian_line.push_back(matrix_value);
        if (hamiltonian.size() == 18) {
            H_R_data.push_back(hamiltonian);
            hamiltonian.clear();
        }

        line_count++;
    }
    hamiltonian.push_back(hamiltonian_line);
    hamiltonian_data.push_back(hamiltonian);

    std::vector<std::vector<double>> k_coordinates = get_k_coordinates(); // Create set of k coordinate vectors for which to perform fourier transform

    // Convert H_R data into Eigen matrices
    std::vector<Matrix18> H_R_data_eigen; // 1155 length vector of 18x18 matrices
    for (int k=0; k<H_R_data.size(); k++){
        Matrix18 H;
        for (int i=0; i<18; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<18; j++) {
                H(i,j) = H_R_data[k][i][j];
            }
        }
        H_R_data_eigen.push_back(H);
    }

    print_message("Data processed. Performing Fourier transform...", starting_time);

    // Perform Fourier transform on H(R) to get H(k)
    Matrix18 H_k_data[k_coordinates.size()]; // 2*N array of 18x18 matrices
    for (int k_index=0; k_index<k_coordinates.size(); k_index++) { // Loop over k points
        for (int R=0; R<1155; R++) { // Loop over R points
            // Calculate dot product k.R
            double k_dot_R = 0;
            for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
                k_dot_R += (k_coordinates[k_index][i] * R_coordinates_data[R][i] * 2 * M_PI);
            }
            std::complex<double> phase_factor = std::polar(1.0, -k_dot_R); // Compute phase factor as e^(-ik.r)

            // Add final value to H(k) at each index
            H_k_data[k_index] += (H_R_data[R] * phase_factor);
        }
    }
    
    print_message("Done.", starting_time);
    
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to implement the FFT algorithm on my dataset but I can't figure out how to manipulate my data to use in the FFTW function.